# Replacing href attribute with data-href attribute using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, tampermonkey

How can I do that for every 'a' tag in a page. My goal is to use this for Google search results to access results without google redirection (used in the href attribute) since the actual link is stored in the data-href attribute. So using Tampermonkey with the following script didn't work, and I don'k know why:

```
$('body').append('<input type="button" value="Fix Href Attributes" id="GG">');
$("#GG").css("position", "fixed").css("top", 18).css("left", 770);   

$('a').each(function(){
                var $currentA = $(this);
                var dataHref = $currentA.attr('data-href');
                $currentA.attr('href',dataHref);
            });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show an example of your `<a>` element(s) before and after manipulation, to show what outcome you want?

Comment: Letting Google know which search result you clicked is *useful*. This feedback is used to continually improve *everyone's* search results. Using a script like the above means you stop contributing to that feedback and just benefit from the feedback provided by others, without reciprocating.

Comment: There's [undirect](https://github.com/xwipeoutx/undirect) for this, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: "Copy Link Address" is an essential function. Until google finds a way to make their redirection without breaking it, I'll keep using undirect.

Comment: @georg: So use a script to put a link next to the main one for that purpose, and use it only when needed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: two links? No, thanks, the results page is already busy enough nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Your code updating the elements is correct, you're just firing it too soon. Fire it in response to the button being clicked:

```
$('body').append('<input type="button" value="Fix Href Attributes" id="GG">');
$("#GG").css("position", "fixed").css("top", 18).css("left", 770).on("click", function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var $currentA = $(this);
        var dataHref = $currentA.attr('data-href');
        $currentA.attr('href', dataHref);
    });
});
```

---

There is, of course, no reason you need to give it an ID and look it up after appending it:

```
$('<input type="button" value="Fix Href Attributes">')
    .css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: 18,
        left: 770
    })
    .on("click", function() {
        $('a').each(function() {
            var $currentA = $(this);
            var dataHref = $currentA.attr('data-href');
            $currentA.attr('href', dataHref);
        });
    })
    .appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Hi T.J. Crowder,
I fire the script using the button but i doesn't work. That's the issue here. Can you try it with tampermonkey and try to diagnose the problem with me?

Here is extra info for tampermonkey:
`// @match *://www.google.com/search?*`
`// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`